# openSUSE 12.3 (64-bit) LiveCD/LiveUSB won't work (MacBook7,1)

Tags: opensuse, macintosh

I wanted to try a live openSUSE 12.3 (64-bit) system on my MacBook 7,1, however:

- When I do it with a LiveUSB created with UNetbootin, it's not recognized as bootable
- When I do it with a LiveCD created with Disk Utility, it boots, but it hangs on the screen with the black-blue background with the openSUSE chameleon on a plant on the right. No matter if I boot it in EFI-mode or not.

What is going wrong? It's not really important however, I just wanted to try it for fun.

Comment: what openSUSE version?

Comment: @peterph 12.3. Added to my question. Sorry for forgetting to include.

Comment: It can easily be broken (frankly, many releases are). Can you try regular installation?

Comment: @peterph Nah, I just wanted to toy around with a live session, I'd rather not install.

Comment: You can create your own iso at  http://susestudio.com - and put in whatever you think you are going to need.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install OpenSuse 12.3 on a Macbook (not Pro) with many problems with the X driver.

Finally I booted, and changed the kernel line beginning with vmlinuz to end with:

```
xdriver=fbdev nomodeset
```

and it worked.